# org-table: hide grid lines

Tags: regular-expressions, faces, org-table, customize

I like how org-mode allows me to quickly create and edit tables. However, I do not like the table's appearance and I would like to modify it.

Customizing the face only lets me change foreground and background color. I want to change the grid only. The essence of this question was asked about 8 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876302/org-mode-table-cells-fontification). Did anything change since then?

I also tried to solve this by font-locking the "|" (pipe/bar) character, however, it seems that my regular expression does not find it reliably and does not set the face.

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode
                                    '((" | " .
                                       'font-lock-keyword-face)))))
```

---

*So my question is:
Can I hide the grid in org-mode tables?*

Comment: If I inspect `font-lock-keywords` in an org buffer I find `("^[  ]*\\(\\(|\\|\\+-[-+]\\).*\\S-\\)" (1 'org-table t))` twice. You probably have to overwrite this somehow. `(" | " (0 font-lock-keyword-face t))` didn't work for me. It's probably overwritten with org-table again. Check this question, maybe it helps: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/40654/19819

Comment: Just so I understand this piece of code correctly: font-lock is already set in org-buffers with a regular expression searching for tables and setting the whole group (`1`) to the face `'org-table`, right? And you tried to overwrite it, but that did not work.


BTW, I managed to hide the |-characters by using `pretty-symbols-mode` and setting `space` as an replacement. However, this changes the |-character, I would just like to show it in a different color.

Comment: Exactly. For some reason sometimes it started to work. But didn't find out why. So it probably is doable.