# Hide table border lines in org mode tables?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table

Is it possible to configure an org-mode table so that all border lines of the table are hidden when exported (e.g. to `.tex`, `pdf` and `HTML`)?

I found [a similar question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/57972) in Emacs.SE but wasn't sure whether it's about the same thing. 
The question asks about font-lock, which I am not familiar with (yet). But I am interested in 
*consistently* and completely hiding the borderlines of a table *in the output* as you could do in MS Word.

Comment: The linked question is different: it wants to hide the grid lines of the table in the emacs buffer where the Org mode file is edited.

Answer (score 2):

For HTML, you can add CSS to hide borders completely. By default, I get a border width of 2 and a rules setting of `group`. You can override these like this:

```
* foo

#+ATTR_HTML: :border 0 :rules none
| a | b |
|---+---|
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
```

For LaTeX/PDF, by default I get just an `\hline` corresponding to the hline that I have in the table separating the header from the body of the table. You can redefine that to nothing:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand{\hline}{}

* foo

#+ATTR_HTML: :border 0 :rules none
| a | b |
|---+---|
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
```

Now both PDF and HTML output have no table borders (horizontal or vertical) at all.